# MATLAB Reconhecimento de figuras geometricas

Tags: matlab

O programa em MatLab tem que ter como entrada uma imagem(preto e branco) e como saída uma string com o nome do formato dessa imagem(circulo,estrela,retângulo,quadrado,elipse). o código que eu fiz esta reconhecendo algumas dessas figuras, mas gostaria de algumas sugestões e dicas para melhorar ele.

```
clear all
close all
im=imread('circulo_fr.jpg');
img=rgb2gray(im);
BW=im2bw(img);
stats=regionprops(BW,'Perimeter','Area','Centroid','BoundingBox');
figure,imshow(BW);
hold on
for k=1:length(stats)
    thisboundingbox=stats(k).BoundingBox;
    if stats(k).Area>10000
        retangulo('Position',[thisboundingbox(1), thisboundingbox(2), thisboundingbox(3), thisboundingbox(4)], 'EdgeColor','r','LineWidth',2);
    else
        retangulo('Position',[thisboundingbox(1), thisboundingbox(2), thisboundingbox(3), thisboundingbox(4)], 'EdgeColor','b','LineWidth',2);
    end
    if stats(k).Perimeter^2/stats(k).Area > 18
        text(stats(k).Centroid(1),stats(k).Centroid(2),'Triangulo','Color','r');
    elseif stats(k).Perimeter^2/stats(k).Area < 14.3
        text(stats(k).Centroid(1),stats(k).Centroid(2),'Circulo','Color','g');
    else
        text(stats(k).Centroid(1),stats(k).Centroid(2),'Quadrado','Color','b');
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

%Esta função é capaz de reconhecer e nomear figuras especificas como 
%retângulos,estrelas, elipses, círculos e triângulos.
%dependendo das figuras e necessário mudar o valor da circularidade

function classificador = Classificador(imagem)

%Esta linha de código recebe uma imagem

```
im=imread(imagem);
```

%Imbinarize cria uma imagem binaria, escolhe o valor limite para minimizar
%a variação intraclasse dos pixels preto e branco com limite

```
img=imbinarize(im,0.3);
```

%Mostra a imagem.

```
imshow(img);


[img numberOfObjcts] = bwlabel(img);
```

%Regionprops mapeia e retorna medidas para o conjunto de propriedades especificado.

```
blobMeasurements = regionprops(img,'Perimeter','Area', 'Centroid');
```

%Circularidade refere-se a razão entre a área de sobreposição do objecto ao círculo equivalente e
%a área total do objecto, através de uma formula matemática esta
%identificando medidas do objeto.

```
circularities = [blobMeasurements.Perimeter].^2 ./ (4 * pi * [blobMeasurements.Area])
hold on;
```

%Este laço de repetição identifica e nomeia a figura geométrica de acordo
%com suas medidas e forma.

```
for blobNumber = 1 : numberOfObjcts    
  if circularities(blobNumber) < 2.1016
    message = sprintf('O objeto é uma estrela',...
    blobNumber, circularities(blobNumber));
    theLabel = 'Estrela';
  end
  if circularities(blobNumber) < 1.6243
      message = sprintf('O objeto é um Triangulo',...
      blobNumber, circularities(blobNumber));
    theLabel = 'Triangulo';      
  end
  if circularities(blobNumber) <1.4095
     message = sprintf('O objeto é um Retangulo',...
     blobNumber, circularities(blobNumber));
     theLabel = 'Retangulo';
  end 
  if circularities(blobNumber) <1.2264
    message = sprintf('O objeto é uma Elipse',...
      blobNumber, circularities(blobNumber));
    theLabel = 'Elipse';  
  end 
  if circularities(blobNumber) <0.9875
     message = sprintf('O objeto é um Circulo',...
     blobNumber, circularities(blobNumber));
     theLabel = 'Circulo';
  end
end  

  text(blobMeasurements(blobNumber).Centroid(1), blobMeasurements(blobNumber).Centroid(2),...
    theLabel, 'Color', 'r');
  uiwait(msgbox(message));
end
```